# What does $\mathbb Z$ \ $2 \mathbb Z$ mean?

Tags: notation

Lately I've taken some interest towards prime number generation.

Apparently this is also a way to express the set of all odd numbers?

> $\mathbb Z$ \ $2 \mathbb Z$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Yes. The backslash means "without" and the slash "factored by". So $\mathbb{Z}\backslash 2\mathbb{Z}=\{\ldots,-5,-3,-1,1,3,5,\ldots\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\cong \{0,1\}.$

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout yeah, I didn't know how to do that :|

Comment: Why not express the odd integers as $1+2\Bbb Z$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the \ symbol means "set-minus" (removing all elements of a set from the elements of a larger set).  So this means all integers minus all integers that are multiples of 2, i.e. all integers minus even integers, which is the set of all odd integers.

Comment: Well, not removing in fact. The meaning of $\;A\setminus B\;$ is taking all the elements in $\;A\;$ that are not in $\;B\;$ . The set $\;B\;$ doesn't need to be a subset of $\;A\;$ .

Comment: Then would N\2N be the set of all positive odd integers? Or should I use Z+\2Z+ instead?